# How to decode booking dates in Wordpress DB

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-database

I ran this query in Wordpress DB and found out that Booking dates are stored in some coded way.

SELECT post_id, meta_id, post_title, meta_key, meta_value
FROM a40443635734677.wp_7n2ncdd4yn_postmeta, a40443635734677.wp_7n2ncdd4yn_posts
where post_id = ID and post_type = 'estate_property'
and meta_key in ('property_price', 'cancellation', 'booking_dates',
'prop_featured', 'min_days_booking') and meta_key = 'booking_dates' and post_id = 248
order by post_id;
Output: a:2:{i:1600646400;i:374;i:1600732800;i:374;}

From UI, it shows that booking dates are sept-21-2020 to sept-23-2020.

how to decode the data from DB (a:2:{i:1600646400;i:374;i:1600732800;i:374;}) to these dates?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to convert it into an array.

```
$dbdata = 'a:2:{i:1600646400;i:374;i:1600732800;i:374;}';

$dbdata = unserialize($dbdata);
```

//result
array (
1600646400 => 374,
1600732800 => 374,
)

Then use PHPs DateTime to convert to human readable format e.g.

```
$returnDate = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', 1600646400);
```

//result
21.09.2020 02:00:00

Answer (score 0):

The larger set of numbers you showed us look like seconds since the Epoch (January 1, 1970).  You could use MySQL's `FROM_UNIXTIME` function convert these epoch values to a bona-fide human readable date.  For example:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1600646400);  -- 21.09.2020 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

That is serialized data. Use PHPs built in `unserialize( your output variable here )`. You'll get an array since the serialized data is an array (`a:2` means array with two indexes).

The date is in UNIX time. You can use PHPs `DateTime` to convert to human readable format.

```
$output = SELECT post_id, meta_id, post_title, meta_key, meta_value 
FROM a40443635734677.wp_7n2ncdd4yn_postmeta, a40443635734677.wp_7n2ncdd4yn_posts 
where post_id = ID 
and post_type = 'estate_property' 
and meta_key in ('property_price', 'cancellation', 'booking_dates', 'prop_featured', 'min_days_booking') and meta_key = 'booking_dates' 
and post_id = 248 order by post_id;

// Unserialize the data.
$unserialized = unserialize($output);

// Get the date for each array key. The date is the $key, so you pass that to the php date function.
foreach( $unserialized as $key => $date ) {
  echo date('M-d-Y', $key ) . "\n";
}
```

This will output `Sept-20-2020` and `Sept-21-2020` with the data you supplied.