# Where are stripe secret keys stored and are they encrypted ? - wordpress / woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

We are building a WordPress site and have integrated Stripe as a payment gateway with the Stripe Plugin. We have inputted our secret key in the Secret Key field found in Woocommerce > Settings > Payments > Stripe

Where is the secret key actually stored (is it stored in source code...db...where?) Someone did suggest it is stored in the database (phpMyAdmin), however, we did check every table but there is no stripe_secrect_key column anywhere to be found.

Also, is the secret key encrypted whereever it may be stored? This maybe a stupid question...

WooCommerce version: 5.6.0

Wordpress version: 5.8

Stripe Gateway Plugin Version: 5.3.0

Kind Regards and TIA

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63903875/14208301

Answer (score 3):

Stripe's keys are stored in `wp_options` table, option is called `woocommerce_stripe_settings`.

And from the look of it, it **does not** seem to be encrypted. `option_value` is filled with a *regular* serialised PHP array.

Comment: it is stored as a JSON key pair value. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce uses a combination of both WordPress database tables and its own custom tables to store its data. However, WooCommerce doesn't have a dedicated table to store the customer data. The customer data is stored in different database tables, which sometimes might make retrieval of this data challenging

Most data plugins store data in the wp_meta DB or it could created a json file to store that API key

Comment: Thanks for the response, which we appreciate, however, still doesn't answer our two key questions :)